# SICP Exercise 1.19 PQ transformation

Tags: sicp

`T(p,q)` transforms the pair `(a,b)` according to `a <-- bq + aq + ap` and `b <-- bp + aq`.

Can someone explain how this transformation works?

Answer (score 0):

Just as you wrote,

```
             T(p,q) 
 (a,      ----------->     ( bq + aq + ap ,
  b)                          bp + aq     )
```

In pseudocode,

```
T(p,q)(a,b) = ( b*q + a*q + a*p , b*p + a*q )
```

The transformation `T(p,q)`, given a pair `(a,b)`, calculates two new values,

```
  a2 = b*q + a*q + a*p   , and
  b2 = b*p + a*q
```

and then constructs a pair, `(a2,b2)`, and returns it as the result.

Comment: questions? doubts? questions?